# Suggest a good video converter for Windows OS

Tags: windows, software-development, video-editing

I need a free video converter that works on Windows OS. It should accept any type of video file as input and also it should be able to convert to any type of video format. Also it should be fast. Which video converter is a good choice ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [FFmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/):

- Free and open-source
- Runs on [Windows](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/)
- Can convert to most types of video format.
- Fast.
- Is CLI.

Answer (score 6):

Currently the *best* video converter is Handbrake. http://handbrake.fr/

- It is a GUI program with a very simple workflow, usually takes next to no time to setup a file convertion. Has several presets ready for fast action.
- Does batch conversion.
- Has some automation (move or rename files after conversion, etc).
- The latest beta supports Intel Quick Sync, so it should be fast.
- Documentations says it will open almost any video format, not specifying exactly what. In my experience I've seen it open some truly obscure and obsolete codec/container combos that many other programs failed at.
- Outputs to MP4 or MKV containers. Codecs:

  - Video Encoders: H.264(x264), MPEG-4 and MPEG-2 (libav), and Theora(libtheora)
  - Audio Encoders: AAC, CoreAudio AAC/HE-AAC (OS X Only), MP3, Flac, AC3, or Vorbis
- It is open source and cross platform (Windows, Mac and Linux).
- Several advanced features as subtitles, chapters, etc.
- There's software built on top of Handbrake that improves the workflow even more, such as: http://vidcoder.codeplex.com/
- Also has CLI tools.

Comment: @NickWilde Question improved following the guidelines.

Answer (score 5):

As normal on any video editing question that is not highly specific I'll recommend my favourite: [AviDemux](http://avidemux.sourceforge.net/). It is not the most intuitive but it has pretty good docs.

[image: AviDemux screenshot]

It is:

- Open Source (and free)
- Cross platform (though I have personally only used it on Windows - XP through 8)
- Encoding in different formats is *fairly* simple. It can open and encode in a [**lot** of formats](http://www.avidemux.org/admWiki/doku.php?id=general:input_formats).
- I would say it is fast. I have not done any benchmarks, however just using it compared to other tools (such as Boilsoft Video) it is much faster.
- It is also pretty good for compressing; quality loss depends on degree of compression - with around 70% compression I had zero **visible** quality loss on a 5 minute video from a concert I organized recently - while reducing from ~517mb -> ~150mb.)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [VirtualDub](http://www.virtualdub.org/):

- Free and open-source
- Runs on [Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BTfJ.jpg)
- Can convert to many types of video format.
- Fast.
- Has a GUI.

[image]